# Multiclass vs Multilabel

Tags: python, analytics, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

Currently, I am working on projects in which I have to classify the restaurant review data. I am using multinomial Naive Bayes algorithm. I am bit confused that my problem is related to multiclass or multilabel.

review example-

> Please treat your customer like customer, not dogs. .I will never go or advice anyone to go at Naivedyam, Hauz Khas.They guys are sick and complete businessman. Food was ver bad in taste, but place and staff were too dirty

It contains three different classes like

```
Bad Experience
Staff Behavior
food quality
```

How to create the training data set?

Should I use multilabel and create the training data set like

```
ID Content                    Tags
1, "content of the review#1", Bad Experience,Staff Behavior,food quality
```

or

like in multiclass

```
 Review          Tags
above review, Bad Experience
above review, Staff Behavior
above review, food quality
```

Any suggestion

Comment: I believe a good approach would be the multi label per `x` approach. That is, for every review `x` there are labels `y` where `y` is a vector with `n` elements (`n` being the number of labels). The values of `y` are zeros and ones (one for the correct labels for each sample).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a [multilabel classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification) example.

One approach is to treat each output response as a separate binary classification problem

```
   X           Y1    Y2 
0  1.438161    0     1
1 -0.283780    1     1
2  0.552564    1     0
3  1.931332    0     1
4  1.656010    0     1
5  0.944862    1     0
```

Where Y1, Y2 is a one-hot encoding of whether "Bad experience" or "Staff behaviour" occurred or not.

You can find a worked out example for multilabel classification in the [scikit-learn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multioutput-classification).